# Django/PostgreSQL not displaying search result

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am unable to retrieve any search results when searching for items. I am using Postgresql and Django. Below is my code. I am not sure if I am not doing the search query right or I just cannot display the results.

I have the search bar in "inventory_management.html". I am trying to get it to where the user searches for an item, and then a list of the displayed items are shown.

**models.py**

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    paid = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    bin = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    listdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    listprice = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    solddate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    soldprice = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    shipdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    shipcost = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product + "\n" + self.description + "\n" + self.paid + self.bin + "\n" + self.listdate + "\n" + self.listprice + "\n" + self.solddate + "\n" + self.soldprice + "\n" + self.shipdate + "\n" + self.shipcost
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')

    if q:
        vector = SearchVector('product', 'description')
        query = SearchQuery(q)

        searchinv = Inventory.objects.annotate(search=vector).filter(search=query)
    else:
        searchinv = None

    return render(request, 'portal/search.html', {"searchinv": searchinv})
```

**inventory_management.html *(where the search bar is located)***

```
{% extends 'portal/base.html' %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
           <form class="d-flex" role="search" action="/search" method="get">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
           <a class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" href="/newitem" type="button">Input New Purchase</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <table class="table table-striped">
       <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Update Item</th>
           <th>Product ID</th>
           <th>Product</th>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th>Purchase Price</th>
           <th>Location</th>
           <th>List Date</th>
           <th>List Price</th>
           <th>Sold Date</th>
           <th>Sold Price</th>
           <th>Ship Date</th>
           <th>Ship Cost</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       {% for inventory in inventory %}
       <tr>
        <td><a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' href='/update/{{inventory.id}}'>Update</a>
        <td>{{inventory.id}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.product}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.description}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.paid}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.bin}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.listdate}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.listprice}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.solddate}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.soldprice}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.shipdate}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.shipcost}}</td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

**search.html**

```
{% extends 'portal/base.html' %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
           <form class="d-flex">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
           <a class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" href="/newitem" type="button">Input New Purchase</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <table class="table table-striped">
       <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Update Item</th>
           <th>Product ID</th>
           <th>Product</th>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th>Purchase Price</th>
           <th>Location</th>
           <th>List Date</th>
           <th>List Price</th>
           <th>Sold Date</th>
           <th>Sold Price</th>
           <th>Ship Date</th>
           <th>Ship Cost</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       {% for inventory in inventory %}
       <tr>
        <td><a class='btn btn-success btn-sm' href='/update/{{inventory.id}}'>Update</a>
        <td>{{inventory.id}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.product}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.description}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.paid}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.bin}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.listdate}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.listprice}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.solddate}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.soldprice}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.shipdate}}</td>
        <td>{{inventory.shipcost}}</td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `inventory` in your view's context, yet you try to use it in template:

```
{% for inventory in inventory %}
```

Change it to:

```
{% for inventory in searchinv %}
```

And it should be better.